# Classic ASP MySQL Wrong Authentication Method

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP site that I just uploaded to a different server, and it is giving the following error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver]Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

I tried doing what is suggested everywhere including the official MySQL website:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/old-client.html

That is, going to the `mysql.user` table and changing the password with the OLD_PASSWORD() function, and changing the `plugin` value to mysql_old_password, and flushing privileges.

For some reason it still doesn't work.

The server is connecting to a remote MySQL server with MySQL 5.6 installed.

The connection string is:

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=server_IP;DATABASE=db_name;UID=user_name;PASSWORD=password;OPTION=3;charset=utf8;stmt=SET CHARACTER SET Hebrew;
```

Comment: Curious: why still using classic ASP ? Technology evolves quite a lot in these years.

Comment: The site was built around 2004, in fact it was built with MSAccess and I converted it to MySQL a while ago, but that's a project that takes 2–3 days for this kind of site (it's quite large and uses just about every type of query that MySQL doesn't like), converting to PHP would take a lot longer and isn't viable at the moment.

Comment: Try `DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}` if you have this driver installed.

Comment: Please add this as an answer, it actually helped :) granted, I needed to return the password type to mysql_native_password etc., but it saved a lot of headaches. Thanks!

Comment: Although, now I have an encoding problem probably related to the change, but it seems like it would be a much easier problem to solve...

Comment: 5.1 is the current version of the driver, 3.51 is older obviously, (although a lot of shared ASP hosting still seems to use it). 5.1 supports utf-8 a lot better than 3.51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection driver should be: `DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}`, therefore the resultant connection string is:

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=server_IP;DATABASE=db_name;UID=user_name;PASSWORD=password;OPTION=3;charset=utf8;stmt=SET CHARACTER SET Hebrew;
```

---

**UPDATE** Here is a list of MySQL ODBC drivers. You can obtain the latest version & view the release notes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-odbc/en/