# ASP classic connection to MySql not working

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I am forced to move an old website that has been running well for years on a remote windows server using classic ASP (VBScript) and MS access databases.

The new hosting company (123-reg) does not support MS Access on their Windows server, so I am now using MySQL. I have used MySQL successfully on other sites but always using PHP rather than classic ASP, so I have never connected to a MySQL database from ASP before.

The website has hundreds of pages and I was hoping that all I had to do was change the connection strings. However I now get a 500 error

> 80004005|[Microsoft] ODBC_Driver_Manager]_Data_source_name_not_found_and_no_default_driver_specified

which has stumped me.

I have tried

```
set Conn=server.createobject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
set rs = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
conn.open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=" & servername & "; DATABASE=" & database & "; UID=" & username & ";PASSWORD=" & pword & "; OPTION=3;"
```

I have also tried:

```
conn.open "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=" & servername & "\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=" & database & ";UID=" & username & ";PWD=" & pword"
```

and after reading [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086883/classic-asp-mysql-wrong-authentication-method) to a similar queation:

```
conn.open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=" & servername & "; DATABASE=" & database & "; UID=" & username & ";PASSWORD=" & pword & "; OPTION=3;charset=utf8;"
```

and still get the same error.

I have hunted the Internet and this site but whenever I find information it assumes that I am using my own server, which I am not. The page at: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/306345 suggests that I make changes to the server registry, which of course I am unable to do, and in any case I find it hard to accept that a company as large as 123-reg has to change things on their server to allow me to connect to a database.

I therefore come to the conclusion that I have something wrong (probably something simple) with my connection coding.

I did raise a ticket with 123-reg but they told me it is a coding problem and they do not help with that, which reinforces my theory.

I would be deeply appreciative for any help on this. I do plan to re-write the site in PHP now and I know that I can make that work well, but as there are hundreds of pages to code it will take me months and I am looking for a quick fix to get the site live again using the current pages whilst I re-write the whole site in PHP.

Many thanks

Tog

Update: 11th January
123-reg have come back to me and said the ODBC version is 5.1.8. I have changed the connection string but still get a 500 error, being:

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Cache-Control: private
>   Content-Length: 250 Content-Type: text/html Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>   Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDCCQSTSCA=FLAJJCCDFENAOEMMCGFGNPCF; path=/
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Wed, 11 Jan 2017 14:46:07 GMT Connection:
>   close An error occurred on the server when processing the URL

There is no line number and no error description.

I have written a simple page to test the connection and my full code is:

```
  <%@ Language=VBScript %>
    <%
    option explicit
    Response.Buffer = true
    '=============================
    'database connection variables
    dim servername, username, pword, database
    servername = "cust-mysql-123-19" 'The name of the Server
    username = "atourist" 'The username for the database
    pword = "redacted for this post" 'The password for the database
    database = "atourist" 'The database to use
    '============================
    dim rs
    dim strSQL
    dim conn
    dim ds
    dim county
    dim numrec
    county="Grampian"
    %>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>]
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
    ' connect to database and retrieve recordset
    set conn=server.createobject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
    set rs = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
    strSQL = "select * from ukgh where county='" & county &  "' ORDER by random ASC"
    conn.open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1.8. Driver}; SERVER=" & servername & "; DATABASE=" & database & "; UID=" & username & ";PASSWORD=" & pword & "; OPTION=3;"
    set rs = conn.Execute(strSQL)
    '===============================
    ds=rs.GetRows()
    rs.close
    conn.close
    set rs = nothing
    set conn = nothing

    'display records
    for Numrec =LBound(ds, 2) To UBound(ds, 2)

    response.write DS(1, numrec) & ", " & DS(2, numrec) & "<br />"

    Next
    %>
    </body>
    </html>
    <%
    response.end
    %>
```

Comment: Is the MySql ODBC 3.51 driver installed? You can [download it here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/3.51.html). The connection string that you want is: `Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;
User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;` (taken from https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-3-51/)

Comment: @Lynn thank you, but I do not have the facility to install drivers as the site is remotely hosted by 123-reg. I have already tried the connection string you suggest (see above) but it does not work.

Comment: Just because the support guys at 123-reg say that it is a coding problem doesn't mean that it is a coding problem. :/ Can you ask them whether the MySQL ODBC 3.51 driver is installed?

Comment: @TogPorter Then you're out of luck. Without the ODBC driver installed, you can't connect to MySql from classic ASP. I'd start down of path of asking them to install it.

Comment: A couple of points. First If your database is MySQL then (obviously) you need a MySQL ODBC conn string - forget the SQL Server one. Version 5.1 is more likely to be installed these days than 3.51, but it would probably be worth your while asking tech support if either is installed. This page is a useful resource. http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql . Second, the Jet (Access) OLEDB driver is still installed on Windows servers by default, so even if they say it isn't supported it might be worth uploading your existing Access database and seeing if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have a 123-reg ticket in asking what MySQL ODBC driver is installed and I am still waiting for a reply - probably tomorrow. Surely there must be one installed, or how can anyone connect with ASP classic pages? I cannot upload the MS Access databases because I need to put them above the root folder but 123-reg do not allow access to that area, and they categorically told me I could not use MS Access.

Comment: Quite.  If you install MySQL on Windows an ODBC driver ships with it.  Version 5.3 seems to be the current one, and for what its worth this is the conn string which works on my laptop `Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 UNICODE Driver};Server=localhost;Database=mydatabase;User=myuserid; Password=mypassword;Option=3;`.

Comment: @John. I really appreciate your help. 123-reg have replied with ODBC version. I have added information and complete code at the bottom of my original post :-)

Comment: I've never seen that error message before, however the fact that you're no longer getting the ODBC_Driver_Manager suggests that your connection string now works and something else later in the page is throwing the error.

Comment: What happens if you strip out everything but the connection and execution of the SQL statement? And are you sure the ODBC driver part of the connection string has a trailing period? All other examples I've seen are 5.1 or 3.51 without a trailing period.

Comment: Eureka! Changing the driver syntax to 5.1 without a trailing period worked. Days of frustration over. Now I can start to re-write the whole site in PHP. many thanks to all for your time and help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your host is a x64 box, try both [x64 connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-1/) with `Provider=MSDASQL` and `MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver` (not sure if you shoud mention "8." in "5.1.8." - "5.1" or "5.2w" should be fine). If it will not help - check if 123-reg provides DSN for databases (you use DSN-less connection) or try to connect with IP of the database.

To ensure this is an asp problem, try to connect from a test php script (Example [[1]](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp), [[2]](https://gist.github.com/chales/11359952)).

Comment: Yes, I did test  a PHP connection when I set up the MySQL database and it worked fine. The problem appears to have been with the MySQL ODBC version. :-)

Answer (score -1):

I add only `Unicode Driver` in connection string 5.3 and problem resolved

Change this :

```
Conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 };SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=psa; UID=admin;PASSWORD=mypassword;Port=8306; OPTION=3"
```

To :

```
Conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 **Unicode Driver**};SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=psa; UID=admin;PASSWORD=mypassword;Port=8306; OPTION=3"
```

Best Regards